# Translation of a Schwartz function is a Schwartz function?

Tags: schwartz-space

If $f\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\tau_{y}f\in S(\mathbb{R^n})$?

$\sup_{x} |x^{\alpha} \partial_{x}^{\beta} \tau_{y}f(x)|<\infty$?

Comment: oh! yes. My mistake

Comment: It is immediate from $(x+y)^\alpha = \sum {c\choose \alpha} x^cy^{\alpha-c}$