# Shifted Schwartz Functions are Schwartz?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, binomial-theorem, schwartz-space

I am asking about the same question as this post: [Translation of a Schwartz function is a Schwartz function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562803/translation-of-a-schwartz-function-is-a-schwartz-function)

Namely: If $f\in S(\mathbf{R}^n)$ and for all $y\in\mathbf{R}^n$ then $\tau_{y}f\in S(\mathbf{R^n})$? Equivalently, is it true that we have $\sup_{x \in \mathbf{R}^N} |x^{\alpha} \partial_{x}^{\beta} \tau_{y}f(x)|<\infty$?

I am not very familiar with the multi index Binomial Theorem and it seems like the result follows from there. Can someone elaborate further why exactly this is true?

Comment: Can you prove this in the very simple one-dimensional case? The general case is just excess notation.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I can see why in the one dimensional case is true. I think I am having trouble thinking about the multi index case because we are not sure if the vector of the shift has all positive terms. So when taking the multi-index power, we will potentially get an oscillating series, wouldn't we?

Comment: $\alpha, \beta$ are multindices of non-negative integers, so I'm not sure what you mean. Again, if this calculation is not clear, you should try it first with a concrete choice of multindices, maybe in dimension 2 say. The general case really is just a notational change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\sup_x |x^\alpha D^\beta f(x-y)| 
&= \sup_x |(x+y)^\alpha D^\beta f(x)| 
\\
&\le \sup_x \sum_{\gamma\le \alpha} C_{\gamma,\alpha}|x|^{|\gamma|} |y|^{|\alpha-\gamma|}  |D^\beta f(x)|
\\
&\lesssim_{\alpha,y} \sum_{\gamma\le \alpha} [f]_{\gamma,\beta}   < \infty 
\end{align}
where $[f]_{\alpha,\beta}$ is the seminorm $[f]_{\alpha,\beta} = \sup_{x} |x^{\alpha}D^\beta f(x)|$.

Comment: So is $\gamma$ also a multi-index? I am not sure what it means here when you wrote $\gamma \leq \alpha$ since both of them are in $\mathbf{N}_0^N$?

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner yes, it means that $\gamma_i \le \alpha_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,N$. Same notation as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Multi-binomial_theorem, and you can find the rest of multi-indices notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! What does it mean when you write $|x|^\gamma$ as in this case we would have $|x| \in \mathbf{R}$ and not $\mathbf{R}^N$ anymore, right? I haven't seen multi index applied onto real numbers before. Moreover, is the semi-norm you wrote down here equivalent to the semi-norm $\sup_x |x^\alpha D^\beta f(x)|$?

Comment: Right, that was me being sloppy. It should be $|x|^{|\gamma|}$, sorry. So yes, to the second question